# How do modify active directory user properties?

Tags: 2010, web-part, active-directory

I use this code for find users in AD

```
  SearchResultCollection results = null;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://...");
                DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
               adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";

                results = adSearcher.FindAll();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

and add a Children

```
 using (DirectoryEntry ou = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Domainname"))
            {

                DirectoryEntry user = ou.Children.Add("CN=" + txtuser.Text, "user");
                int NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x200;
                int PWD_NOTREQD = 0x20;
                user.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = txtuser.Text;
                user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = NORMAL_ACCOUNT | PWD_NOTREQD;
                user.Properties["displayName"].Value = txtname.Text;
                user.Properties["mail"].Value=txtemail.TemplateControl;
                user.Properties["description"].Value = txtnote.Text;
                user.CommitChanges();
                user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { txtpass.Text });
            }
```

How do modify active directory user properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post for detailed examples on how active directory properties are retrieved and updated - http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm